# Prefer const literals as parameters of constructors on @immutable classes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am following the example of [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial) tutorial.

If I want to add two text components to a children array and I get the title warning.

For example:

```
Widget titleSection = Container(
  child: Row(
    //need to expand the rows on the column
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Hello1',
            ),
            const Text(
              'Hello2',
            ),
          ],
      )         
    ],
  ),
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it should be

```
    Widget titleSection = Container(
      child: Row(
        //need to expand the rows on the column
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'Hello1',
                ),
                Text(
                  'Hello2',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Actually the warning is the same after changing according to your code, but the program works fine. See [link](https://i.imgur.com/CftvXUo.png)

Comment: I don't see any "const" after children, before [ in your screen

Comment: @wokdertalik Sorry, I didn't noticed. It works now. Thanks